# Sources not authenticating properly error on update

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, updates

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the latest VirtualBox.  All went as expected.  I then tried to apply the 260 odd updates it needed, as per usual.  What I then get is a message about the sources not authenticating properly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? Are you trying upgrade via Software Center or terminal? You can give a shot to terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code per the 3rd answer from [this page](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/179397) and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5
sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with certificate validation.

Fire up the Update Manager again and right click on the update list to select "uncheck all", then scroll down to near the bottom of the list, where you'll find an entry for "Utility for updating packages" (or words to that effect).  Select -only- this update and apply.  After this update is done, all of the others will work normally.